# git-svn migration and git workflow

Tags: git, migration, workflow, git-svn

I have migrated a project from svn to git.
svn had 1)trunk 2)branch1 3)branch2
trunk in svn was a useless and it been out of sync for years with branch1 and branch2.(I am not responsible:))

branch1 is being merged to branch2 on weekly basis.

Project using branch2 want to migrate to GIT.
So I did git-svn clone and have a git repo that is having master=svn trunk, banch1=svn branch1 and branch2= svn branch2.

I will have to keep rebasing branch 1 from svn and merge it to branch2 on a weekly basis.MY understanding is that trunk in svn should be same as master in git for the rebase to work. So I believe the only option left to me is to merge branch 2 to trunk in svn (remember my svn trunk is useless) and rebase it will my git master.Delete branch2 in git (as master is my branch2) , Rebase branch1 from svn on a weekly basis and merge branch1 to master in git.Is there any better way?

If some git gurus are patient enough to read this and respond I will be grateful:)

Answer (score 0):

Just do a `git svn fetch` in your `git-svn` clone and then merge branch1 to branch2 in Git. Should work without big problems.

Comment: Thanks Vampire:) I have figured the git svn synch part ...I was trying to validate my approach